# bmi app crashes when calculate button pressed

Tags: android, button, crash

I'm a android beginner (my first post) and get a crash on running this bmi calculator tutorial: http://android-meda.blogspot.co.uk/2012/01/writing-your-first-android-app-body.html?m=1

Launched on my phone, the screen goes black with the message "BMI has stopped unfortunately". I'm not sure where to diagnose the problem so any help would be much appreciated.
Thank you

```
04-04 14:14:44.750: E/SensorManager(24999): thread start
04-04 14:14:44.755: D/SensorManager(24999): registerListener :: handle = 0  name=  LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42b75490
04-04 14:14:44.760: D/SensorManager(24999): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42b75490
04-04 14:14:44.760: D/Sensors(24999): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
04-04 14:14:44.760: I/Sensors(24999): sendDelay --- 200000000
04-04 14:14:44.765: D/SensorManager(24999): JNI - sendDelay
04-04 14:14:44.765: I/SensorManager(24999): Set normal delay = true
04-04 14:14:44.815: D/SensorManager(24999): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42b75490
04-04 14:14:44.870: D/libEGL(24999): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
04-04 14:14:44.875: D/libEGL(24999): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
04-04 14:14:44.880: D/libEGL(24999): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
04-04 14:14:44.885: D/(24999): Device driver API match
04-04 14:14:44.885: D/(24999): Device driver API version: 10
04-04 14:14:44.885: D/(24999): User space API version: 10 
04-04 14:14:44.885: D/(24999): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Tue Oct 16 15:37:13 KST 2012 
04-04 14:14:44.910: D/OpenGLRenderer(24999): Enabling debug mode 0
04-04 14:14:44.985: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24999): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
04-04 14:14:52.235: D/SensorManager(24999): unregisterListener::  Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42b75490
04-04 14:14:52.235: D/Sensors(24999): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
04-04 14:14:52.235: I/Sensors(24999): sendDelay --- 200000000
04-04 14:14:52.235: D/SensorManager(24999): JNI - sendDelay
04-04 14:14:52.235: I/SensorManager(24999): Set normal delay = true
04-04 14:14:52.240: D/SensorManager(24999): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= LSM330DLC 3-axis Accelerometer delay= 200000 Listener= android.view.OrientationEventListener$SensorEventListenerImpl@42b78da8
04-04 14:14:52.260: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24999): getSelectedText on inactive InputConnection
04-04 14:14:52.265: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24999): setComposingText on inactive InputConnection
04-04 14:14:52.265: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(24999): getExtractedText on inactive InputConnection

04-04 14:14:53.420: D/AndroidRuntime(24999): Shutting down VM
04-04 14:14:53.420: W/dalvikvm(24999): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41f052a0)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3691)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17267)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3686)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    ... 11 more
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    at com.example.bmi.MainActivity.calculateClickHandler(MainActivity.java:22)
04-04 14:14:53.430: E/AndroidRuntime(24999):    ... 14 more
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are somewhere trying to cast a TextView into an EditText:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
```

Check your code for something like (TextView) variable = (EditText) findViewById(..)...

The problem is on line 22 in your MainActivity.java file.

If you analyze the stack trace you pasted:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.TextView cannot be cast to android.widget.EditText
at com.example.bmi.MainActivity.calculateClickHandler(MainActivity.java:22)
```

It points you to where the problem is (MainActivity.java:22). This means line 22 from your MainActivity.java file.

Better, if you can't find the issue, paste a code snippet here so I can point more specifically to the problem. You should post the code from the onClick listener

EditText is used to edit text and TextView is a component used to display text. Therefore they are not compatible. The first is an editable form element while the latter is just for displaying purposes. You cannot cast one into another.

Comment: Thank you Slacky. I appreciate your help with this.  Line 22 falls within this block:       private String interpretBMI(float bmiValue) {
  
  if (bmiValue < 16) {
   return "Severely underweight";
  } else if (bmiValue < 18.5) {
   return "Underweight";
  } else if (bmiValue <25) {
   return "Normal";
  } else if (bmiValue <30) {
   return "Overweight";
  } else {
   return "Obese";
  }

Comment: I'm not sure you're looking at the correct bit of code there gdh48k, as @Slacky is correct there's a widget cast error causing it, in an `onClick` method

Comment: Thanks Matt.  Is this relevant?   if (view.getId() == R.id.calculateButton) {
   
   EditText weightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.weightText);
   EditText heightText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.heightText);
   TextView resultText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.resultLabel);
   
   float weight = Float.parseFloat(weightText.getText().toString());
   float height = Float.parseFloat(heightText.getText().toString());
    
   float bmiValue = calculateBMI(weight, height);
   
   String bmiInterpretation = interpretBMI(bmiValue);
   
   resultText.setText(bmiValue + "-" + bmiInterpretation);

Comment: @Slacky and Matt Taylor - your help was invaluable! I'd somehow mistakenly typed EditText in the TextView line. It's now corrected and the app runs fine.  Thank you both so much :)